# How can we implement the transport security in WCF service

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have created WCF Service and the the Service Call on Android app.how can we implement the transport Security for make the Connection Secure of Webservice and Client app.

Comment: Have you found [Transport security overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-overview) and [Transport Security - WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security) ?

Comment: You should add to the question, that this is your main "showstopper". It will attract more useful answers (or any for that matter). As is, the question is probably going to be closed as being not focused enough or a similar reason.

Comment: You can refer to this link for information about how the WCF service securely communicates with the Android application: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45f62086-7800-48c5-afbe-e2ff7f28dbe6/using-certificates-with-wshttpbinding-to-secure-iphone-android-and-windows-phone-over-message?forum=wcf